# How to cache results of a function in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I would like to know if it is possible to store the results of a function in cache for each possible outcome.

This is not an exact example below, the real example is a lot more complex and I need to cache the results for speed reasons, but this gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish

For example I have a function that retrieves the users comments:

```
public function getUserComments(User $user)
{
    $comments = DB::table('comments')->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
    return $comments;
}
```

I need to save all the possible outcomes for each individual user in my system so essentially.

For example if I have 100 users:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
       $cachedResults [] = $user->getUserComments();
}
```

Now I have the cached results that are faster to look through:
$cachedResults

Comment: Have you looked at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache?

Comment: Not clear if you're trying to make use of a cache store, or just wanting to cache the items in a variable for that execution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick(not tested):

```
public function getUserComments(User $user)
{
    $key = "comments-${$user->id}";

    $comments = Cache::remember($key, 60, function () {
        return DB::table('comments')->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
    });

    return $comments
}
```

60 is the amount of minutes here. You have to configure your cache if you want something other than  the default, which is the `file` cache driver.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Stephan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844641/2343305), you may save the value with a specific key or, you can use [tags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#cache-tags), something like:

```
Cache::tags(['users', $name])->remember('model', 60, function () {
    // [...]
});
```

I prefer this second approach because it's easiear to manage if you make some changes on your database...

For example you can use the `['users', $name]` tags in order to store multiple keys that refers to a specific user, for example the `comments` relation.

When you make a change to the user model, you will only refresh the `['users', $name]` tags with 'model' key.

If you delete the user, you will flush the `['users', $name]` tags and if you perform a mass delete, you will flush the `users` tag in order to clear all the stored users in cache.

Of course you have to use the cache drivers that allow tags.